# How to calculate difference between two dates in hours?

Tags: javascript

As I am new to javascript so I am asking this question how to find difference between two dates in hours.I am successfully calculated difference but when I give time in format of AM/PM it gives me output as NAN Please check my code I am posting below and thanks in advance:

```js
function calculateTime() {
  var d2 = new Date('2018-02-12 03:00:00 AM');
  var d1 = new Date('2018-02-10 08:00:00 AM');
  var seconds =  (d2- d1)/1000;
  var hours = seconds/3600;
  console.log(hours);
}
calculateTime();
```

Comment: Works for me https://jsfiddle.net/u7krsbqr/ also, this is not jQuery, this is Javascript

Comment: still it gives output as Nan

Comment: If your code gives you NaN, then you aren't using the same code you posted here. The code you pasted here works - see the fiddle.

Comment: Gives NaN for me on Android Firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox will return Invalid date for the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS AM`

One option is to use year, month, day separately on `new Date()`

> new Date(year, month [, day [, hours [, minutes [, seconds [,
>   milliseconds]]]]]);

Like:

```js
function calculateTime() {
  var formatDate = function(dt) {
    let n = dt.split(/\D/).splice(0,6);
    n[3] = dt.slice(-2) === 'PM' ? ( +n[3] + 12 ) : n[3]; //Update Hour
    n[1] = n[1] - 1; //Update month
    return n;
  }

  var d2 = new Date(...formatDate('2018-02-12 03:00:00 AM'));
  var d1 = new Date(...formatDate('2018-02-10 08:00:00 AM'));

  var seconds = (d2 - d1) / 1000;

  var hours = seconds / 3600;
  console.log(hours);
}

calculateTime();
```

Doc: [new Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: A lot simpler to just use `dt.split(/\D/)`. Also, *h* is a string so `h + 12` will do concatenation, not addition, `+h + 12` will fix that.

Comment: Good idea. Thanks @RobG

Answer (score 2):

Simply subtract the date objects from one another.

```
var hours = Math.abs(date1 - date2) / 36e5;
```

The subtraction returns the difference between the two dates in milliseconds. 36e5 is short for 60*60*1000 and so dividing by 36e5 will give you hours.

Comment: it is giving me hours when i remove AM from date but i want time in AM/PM format

Comment: That's essentially what the OP is doing. The issue is incorrectly parsing to Date initially.